# Retrieve all columns from Hbase Get except specifc column names

Tags: java, hbase

I have an Hbase Table containing different set of column names for every row key. The job I am trying to complete is to ignore certain columns from Get. i.e, The Result object would only contain name-value pairs where the names didn't match the ignore list.

I know about **MultipleColumnPrefixFilter** but what I need is inverse of this filter.

Do we have this feature built-in hbase API or do I need to write a filter for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at HBase's SkipFilter.
It basically adds as a wrapper to your existing Filter and instead of FILTERING IN your lines, it FILTERS THEM OUT.
https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/SkipFilter.html

This is readily available out of the box and are very easy to use.

Comment: SkipFilter is used to skip rows from output. I need to keep the row, just that i don't want specific columns.